# Surface mount troffer on ceiling

Tags: brackets

I found these [2x4 LED troffers](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-5000-Lumen-2ft-x-4ft-White-LED-Multi-Volt-Flat-Panel-Troffer-2-Pack-PN324A50A1-40/305543510) at a big box store. I'd like to surface mount them on my basement ceiling. I have low ceilings and they are only a half inch thick. They would be perfect. Can you think of an appropriate u-shaped bracket, corner bracket, or rail I could mount to the ceiling and then slide these into? They weigh about 3kg/7lbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you plan to get 2 of 4' pieces of C channel and screw it to your ceiling 2' apart then slide the troffer in from one end.

[image]

not to scale

possibly you could use two of [these drop ceiling edge moldings](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DONN-Brand-12-ft-x-7-8-in-x-7-8-in-Suspended-Ceiling-Wall-Molding-SM7/100346094)
 riveted together to form a C

Else you could get a sheet-metal place to fold C channel for you, or see what you can find in aluminum extrusions.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. I think they are great.